# Error: Undefined function or variable - java in MATLAB

Tags: java, matlab, javafx

I would like to run a simple media player made in Java from MATLAB, more precisely this one: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/mediaplayerjava.htm

This code compiles without any problems and works, both when trying to run it in IntelliJ and when compiling with `javac` and running the .class file.

It compiles successfully under the same Java version as my MATLAB is using, so I am telling where the java-files are with `javaaddpath(pwd)`. For some reason I get the error "Undefined function or variable 'MediaPlayer' while running the code provided in the link above, doing like this: `test = MediaPlayer` or `test = MediaPlayer();` To be sure that everything is working I tried to compile and then run a simple java Hello World in MATLAB, which was working fine.

What could be the problem? If you have time, please help me out by compiling the code from the link above (2 files, press "Next Page for the second java file) and try to run it in MATLAB. I would be extremely thankful for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer:**

The `MediaPlayer` is defined in package `mediaplayer` in your Java(FX) code:

```
package mediaplayer;
```

Therefore, the correct initialization would be:

```
test = mediaplayer.MediaPlayer();
```

**Long answer:**

From this point this question becomes really JavaFX specific and not about the trivial Matlab - Java interopability.

Problems:

- JavaFX is bundled inside Java8 by default, and even Matlab R2016 is shipped with Java7, therefore the JavaFX package (`javafx.*`) will be not on the classpath of the JVM of Matlab, so you must ensure that JavaFX on the classpath of the JVM.
- As soon as you manage to launch the `Application` (e.g. `test = mediaplayer.MediaPlayer(); test.main({''});`), it will block the Matlab thread. Even worse, when you close the window, the `Application` will still not exit and the Matlab thread remains blocked. This can be worked around by calling [`setImplicitExit(true)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Platform.html#setImplicitExit-boolean-) in the `start` method of the `Application`. This will force the `Application` to exit when all the `Stage`s are closed, therefore the Matlab thread is not blocked anymore.
- At this point the problem is that an `Application` cannot be started more than once. So if you have exited, you will be never able to start the same `Application` again.

What you can do to handle the last two points is to implement an "Application starter" in Java that runs on a separated thread and usable to execute JavaFX Applications.

Comment: I actually removed the package in the code, therefore I compile it like described. Anyways, the problem is still there. You have right about Matlab R2016 is shipped with Java7, therefore I compile the code like this (OS X): javac -source 1.7 -target 1.7 MediaPlayer.java and it works, I can press on the class file and the media player will run. I will try to add the JavaFX package to my MATLAB JVM.

Regarding the problems you mention, this information was very valuable to me, many thanks! PS. Is there any good source for this kind of info regarding MATLAB and Java?

Comment: I had to connect Matlab backend with JavaFX frontend in the past, and those days there were nothing really worthy material on this topic. The content of this answer is actually the problems what I have faced doing the task, and the solutions were coming mostly from experimenting and reading the documentation of JavaFX (especially the javadoc of `Application` class can be really valueable to understand why things happen:) ).